# CakePHP 3 : findById where greater than 0

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.2

I am paginating associated model in `view()` function of another model.

```
public function view($id = null)
    {
        $category = $this->Categories->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Subcategories']
        ]);

        // paginate products
        $products = $this->paginate($this->Categories->Products->findByCategoryId($category->id, ['conditions' => ['stock >' => 0, 'selling_price >' => 0]]), [
          'limit' => 21
        ]);

        $this->set('products', $products);
        $this->set('category', $category);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['category']);
    }
```

I want to restrict data to find where `stock` and `selling_price` is greater than 0.

But this is not working. How to apply conditions on `findById` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

`$products = $this->paginate($this->Products->findByCategoryId($categoryId)->where(['stock >' => 0, 'selling_price >' => 0])->limit(21))`;

with $categoryId given.